# Trying to call subroutine by clicking a button and receive Compile Error: Sub or Function not defined

Tags: vba, compiler-errors, excel-2016

I'm trying to create a button that clears data from a table and then restores any lost formulas as needed.

I already have code that will clear a table and leave the header row and one body row. I used it on `Sheet 2` with another button. The button under construction is on `Sheet 1`.

In the picture, you can see the top of the sub I want to call `Public Sub CleanTheTable` and the code for the button `Sub cmd_ClearTable_Click`.

I'm very new to VBA, so I'm not sure what the titles at the top of the windows mean (I'm guessing the second one is the button, but if something is general, can't I call it with just the `Call` command?).  Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Move the `CleanTheTable` code to a regular module, instead of the sheet code module.

Comment: Or use `Sheet2.CleanTheTable` (note that the `Call` is optional).

Comment: Finally found where a general module would be.  That worked!  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Right-click the `VBAProject` and insert a module.

Place the **function** `CleanTheTable` in the module and give the module a meaningful name, like `Tables`. This way you can organize your code, plus you probably want to use the function in multiple sheets, so it's best not to place the code in one specific sheet.

You can call (use) the function without the `call` keyword like this:

```
CleanTheTable
```

[image: New module]